# Can a .NET program detect whether the O/S version has reached end-of-life and is no longer receiving security patches

Tags: .net, security, operating-system, version, versioning

In the .NET framework is there a way to detect whether the O/S version running on a target deployment machine has reached its end-of-life and is thus no longer receiving O/S security patches?  We need to know the answer to that specific question to determine which team should have responsibility for preventing a situation where a .NET app is running on such a machine.